# Estimating Coefficients for Piecewise Function

Tags: splines, optimization

I'm interested in fitting a piecewise defined function to the following data, so that I get something like:
[image]

```
x = c(2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,2007,2006,2005,2003,2002,2001,2000,1999,1998,1996)
y = c(397,332,377,425,467,611,882,906,1032,955,843,895,873,943,898,476)
```

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
d & if \mbox{ x} < 2007 \\
ax^2 + bx + c & if \mbox{ x} \geq 2007
\end{cases}
$

I also want $f(x)$ to be continuous and differentiable, which it will be except for at $x=2007$, unless we apply some constraints.

To be continuous
$
\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2007^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2007^-}= f(2007) \\
$

In my example that means

$
d = a(2007)^2+b(2007)+c
$

To be differentiable, the derivatives must equal at the knot $x=2007$.

$
0 = 2a(2007) + b \\
b = -4014a
$

I've tried to program this in R

```
f = function(theta,y,x){
  a = theta[1] 
  b = -4014*a
  c = theta[2]
  d = a*2007^2+b*2007+c
  mu = ifelse(x>=2007,a*x^2+b*x+c,d)
  nll = -sum(dnorm(y,mu,1,log=TRUE))
  nll
}

fit = optim(par=c(4.032e-02,1.632e+05),f,y=y,x=x,method='BFGS')
```

I may have bad starting values, as the objective functions's values doesn't change.  Am I going about this the right way?  Perhaps there's something more stable?

Comment: Have you considered "eureqa"?

Comment: Why not splines?

Comment: Some work gives $y = 895.295773117854*logistic(0.113191836803662^(x - 2007.8770718086)) $ 
or $y = 900.098469814448*logistic((2007.96181334671/x)^(x*log(x)))$
where logistic is defined on the following link: http://formulize.nutonian.com/documentation/eureqa/general-reference/building-blocks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to your question. But the answer comes from basic concepts of splines. I think looking further into that topic will be very helpful for you!

If you want to make sure that your estimated $f(x)$ is continuous and follows the form that you propose, the easiest way to do this is to expand the $x$ basis. For example, if you want $f(x)$ to be a constant if $x < 2007$ but quadratic after that, you can simply have the covariates

$x_{0,i} = 1$

$x_{1,i} = x - 2007$ if $x >= 2007$ else 0

$x_{2,i} = (x - 2007)^2$ if $x >= 2007$ else 0

Then you can use simple linear regression to fit $y \sim~ x_0 + x_1 + x_2$. To get your given predictions for a new value of $x$, you just need to get your expansion into $x_0$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ and plug your regression estimates. Note that this will insure a fit that is always continuous, constant before 2007 and quadratic after 2007.

While I do believe this answers your question as asked, I will also comment that this is not how I would attempt to model a non-linear effect; you've built very strong restrictions into your model, which I'm guessing were motivated *post-hoc* by examining your data. This would make the generalization of your results very questionable.  Using standard spline methods would lead to more reliable estimation.

Comment: I'll take a look at splines, this looks to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use OLS for this problem as follows

OLS regression

```
m<-lm(y~I(1*(x<2007))+I(x^2*(x>=2007))+I(x*(x>=2007))+I(1*(x>=2007))+0)
```

In order to satisfy your constraints on differentiability, however, you can use `nls`

```
m2<-nls(y~(a*2007^2-4014*a*2007+c)*I((1)*(x<2007))+
  a*I((x^2)*(x>=2007))+(-4014*a)*I((x)*(x>=2007))+c*I((1)*(x>=2007)),
  start=list(a=2.575e+01,c=1.042e+08),control=list(tol=1e-02))
```

Given the constraints and the data, however, the fit is poor

```
plot(y~x)
lines(x,fitted.values(m),col="red")
lines(x,fitted.values(m2),col="blue")
```

[image: OLS and NLS fit]

Comment: @a-webb Thanks, but I need to guarantee that at $x=2007$ the function will be continuous and differentiable.  I don't think your method will guarantee that.

Comment: You are correct, you'd need the `nls` version of the same, using starting values from the OLS version.

Comment: Added NLS version.